# Is there any Query Retrieve SCP client which supports IPV6?

Tags: dicom

I am using DVTK for my various needs for testing DICOM related functionalists with my application. Unfortunately the Query Retrieve SCP  client doesn't support IPV6 format. Any other utilities are there to allow to query data using IPV6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo could try dcmqr (*1) from the package dcm4che2 (*2).

I have only used that tool on IPv4 environments. According to the documentation, some packages of the toolkit do support IPv6:

> To specify a port with an IPv6 address, enclose the IPv6 address in
>   square brackets before appending the colon and decimal port number

I have not found specific indications about support for IPv6 in the Q/R tool, so, you will have to test it on your environment.

(*1) http://www.dcm4che.org/confluence/display/d2/dcmqr

(*2) http://www.dcm4che.org/confluence/display/d2/dcm4che2+DICOM+Toolkit